# How to compile/build ubuntu eoan os source code?

Tags: 19.10

I have downloaded ubuntu 19.10(eoan) source code and have no idea how to compile/build

Please help me in building the source.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingSoftware  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingTransmission  (this one is old, but uses transmission as an example & thus is rather relevant)

Comment: Ubuntu itself consists of *many many* packages, and the builds take awhile... Probably the most useful if you want to get involved (or just learn) is look at packaging (http://packaging.ubuntu.com/singlehtml/ & others), start with an existing package you want to change, edit & test that, then upload it for testing on other systems via your own PPA.  That isn't actually difficult at all as many guides exist, and it's most of the work packagers do (except for the reviews, discussions/meetings etc)

Comment: What kind of "19.10(eoan) source code" did you download. There is no single "Ubuntu source code" anywhere as far as I know?

Comment: @Pilot6 Like android aosp i want to build and flash the ubuntu os. That is my need.May be later i will try creating or modifying the drivers/debugging. guide me with proper steps if i am wrong. thanks